# View diff with diff tool between last commit and current status

Tags: git, github

I know this must be a very basic question but I'm brand new to `git`.

I want to launch the diff tool (`Meld` in my case) to see the differences between my latest push (the status in the master branch in `Github`) and the current status of my repo. I have not committed any changes yet and if I run `git status` I see that some files have changed since my last commit+push.

I've tried

```
git diff --cached --color
```

but it does nothing.

What command should I use?

Comment: Try without `--cached`.

Comment: Thanks @JohnZwinck, that shows the diffs but in the terminal. How can I see them in Meld?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `git difftool`.  That should launch your configured "difftool" from your ~/.gitconfig.

Comment: Well, that was easier than I expected. Thank you John!